# in PyOpengl to bind text to an object

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Is it possible in PyOpengl to bind text to an object? If I need dynamic changing text to be anchored to a specific object and move along with the object. Please,could you tell me how if it's possible. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you repeat the question? [Is it possible in PyOpengl to bind text to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679505/is-it-possible-in-pyopengl-to-bind-text-to-an-object). How to draw text, see the answers to [How to render text with PyOpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836707/how-to-render-text-with-pyopengl) or [pygame + opengl = display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67608968/pygame-opengl-display-text).

Comment: What do you mean by *"bind text to an object?"*? You must render the text. There is no "drawText" or "bindText" function. What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

A text must be rendered. There is no *drawText* or *bindText* function.

The glyphs of text are often represented by textures. The textures can be generated with the [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/) library ([freetype-py](https://pypi.org/project/freetype-py/)). You can find an example in the answer to the question [How to render text with PyOpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836707/how-to-render-text-with-pyopengl).

You can also use PyGame to generate the text with the [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) or [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module. For an example of how to render text with PyOpenGL and PyGame, see the answer to question [pygame + opengl = display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67608968/pygame-opengl-display-text)